# update preferences values after changing them programatically

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, updates

i've got a simple PreferenceActivity.
in my activity im using the values stored in those keys.
through `getDefaultSharedPreferences` and `getBoolean("somekey")`

if i now change the preference associated with "somekey", everything works fine and
the getBoolean returns the right value.

but if i set the value "somekey" to another value programatically,
via `Preferences.Editor` the settings view doesn't update to the new value!
like this:

```
pref_edit.putBoolean("somekey", true);
pref_edit.commit();
```

if "somekey" was true before, and i now get the value via `getBoolean("somekey");`
it is `true` like what i changed it to, but the checkbox inside the preferences misses this change.
why? how can i update the preferences view?

Comment: The issue might be in your code of checkbox, post that to let us see

Comment: are you talking about changing the value while you're sitting on the preference screen?  The checkbox likely only evaluates its state in onResume so it won't constantly be polling for changes in the Preferences.  You will need to manually toggle the checkbox if the underlying value changes while you're on the screen.

Comment: im changing the value in the activity via `putBoolean(...)` and then im opening the preferences and they dont notice that -.- you can easily rebuilt this scenario. just a checkboxpreference, and change the value of its key in the activity

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but perhaps you need to finish your pref activity when you come out of it the first time as chances are that you are seeing the pref activity "from the stack" that was created earlier. I'm not sure if Pref activity checks for updated values `onResume()`

Comment: hm im finishing it, but if i wouldnt, how could i force the preferences to update?

Comment: @Saqib: no it's not the checkbox - it is an issue indeed

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, valid question and it's not an easy one - some people say `finish`, some others [say](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13403122/281545)

```
setPreferenceScreen(null);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

and what I ended up doing to avoid such measures and the mess they cause on tablets and the like is to register an [`SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) (make my preferences activity into one that is) and when I detect a change in the preferences to update my checkbox (if its value disagrees with the stored preference - so it was not changed manually, cause if changed manually I have an `onClick` which changes the default shared preferences). Annoying indeed.