# SharedPreferences dependencies

Tags: android, dependencies, sharedpreferences, listpreference

I wanted to create ListPreference which, when changed will also reload values of others ListPreference objects. I tried to do that by calling:

```
if(key.equals("important_pref")) {
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  editor.putString("some_pref", "some_val");
  editor.apply();
}
```

in onSharedPreferenceChanged function.

It does the work but I need to reload preferences screen to see the efect. Is there a way to avoid that and reload values instantly?

My guess is that I can't do this that way, because the first commit needs to be ended before changing something else.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common requirement that is unfulfilled I'm afraid. You either have to reload the screen by hacks like `setPreferencesScreen(null);` or (better) register a SharedPreferencesChanged listener and update the prefs manually. See : [update preferences values after changing them programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171530/update-preferences-values-after-changing-them-programatically/21177514#21177514)

In your case you should add if clauses in your existing SharedPreferencesChanged listener to "hear" the change in the `"some_pref"` preference and update the displayed value manually.