# Update preference screen UI manually

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I've got a setting screen with preferences in my app.

I use PreferenceFragmentCompat and usual AppCompatActivity. When I change state of some preference(f.e. SwitchPreferenceCompat) and tap on it then the Android preference framework will change its internal state and upgrade preference UI. Thats pretty good.

In one usecase I have to change internal preference state manually and then I must change preference UI manually but I didn't find any **invalidate**-method to upgrade preference-UI.

I load preference screen with its children and them states in **onCreatePreferences**

```
override fun onCreatePreferences(bundle: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {

    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)

}
```

but when I return on that screen(after another activity is finished) I should refresh preference-UI according to its new internal state.

Is there anyone who khows how to do it manually (I'm aware that this workflow is not native)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you refresh PreferenceActivity to show changes in the settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003098/how-do-you-refresh-preferenceactivity-to-show-changes-in-the-settings)

Comment: try overriding onPreferenceChanged() method

Comment: I use the descendants of  PreferenceFragmentCompat and usual AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Yes, I can manually change SwitchPreferenceCompat state by setting setChecked(true/false) to it. But the last problem is when should I call it, in what callback?! When I setup listener(setOnPreferenceChangeListener) to SwitchPreferenceCompat-object then it isn`t fired! Now I call update in onStart but I think it's not the best solution.